# Как соединить две прямые дугой заданного радиуса?

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

Имеется три точки (ABC), соединенные линиями. Точки могут быть любыми.
Необходимо "сгладить" угол между нимим, вписав туда дугу, заданного радиуса.
Я не знаю с чего начать. не известны ни центр дуги, ни касательные.

Контекст задачи: это маршрут для судна, каждая путевая точка имеет свойство "радиус поворота". Мне необходимо его визуализировать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Провести (аналитически, понятно...) прямую, параллельную AB на расстоянии R, и прямую, параллельную BC на том же расстоянии R. Их пересечение дает точку X3. После чего найти X1 и X2 не проблема — проведя перпендикуляры.

Comment: Точка x3 - находится на биссектрисе угла ABC. В треугольнике X1-X3-B угол X1 - прямой, а угол B -  половина угла ABC, а отрезок X1-X3 равенн R. Из этого треугольника находим длину отрезка X1-B.